# Как сформировать красивые адреса при использовании форм?

Tags: yii2

вот собственно форма

```
<?php $form=ActiveForm::begin(['action'=>Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/serial/category/search']),'method'=>'get']); ?>
 <?= Html::textInput('query','',['placeholder'=>'Поиск']) ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>') ?>
        </div>
        <?php $form=ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

вот так пытаюсь поймать её в rules urlManager.

```
'/serial/category/search/<query>' => '/serial/category/search',
            '/serial/category/search/<query:\w*>' => '/serial/category/search',
            '<module:serial>/<controller:category>/<action:searh>/<query>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:serial>/<controller:category>/<action:searh>/<query:\w*>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>/<query>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
            '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>/<query:\w*>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
    '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:(\w|-)+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
```

срабатывает только правило  правило соответственно приходит такой строка

```
http://site.com/serial/category/search?query=Запрос
```

Все эти тело движения для того  бы получить такого плана запрос 
`http://site.com/serial/category/search/Запрос` где я туплю не подскажите ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что адрес "куда слать" формируется на стороне клиента и он ничего не знает о ваших правилах в url-менеджере. Фактически он берет то что в экшене и добавляет сериализованные параметры из формы.
Что бы получить такой адрес, как вы хотите, то по нажатию на кнопку или по сабмиту, надо сделать редирект на нужную страницу джаваскриптом. Что-то вроде:

```
window.location = $('.search-form').attr('action') + '/' + $('.search-input').val();
```